# Invalid selected Titanium SDK "3.1.0.GA"

Tags: android, titanium, version

After I re-install the Titanium, I was unable to open my previous android app file (which is before Titanium 3.2), any idea what happen?

Answer (score 1):

What actually do you mean by "unable to open my previous android app file"? I suppose, that the new installed version Titanium, doesn't support the 3.1.x SDK, so you can't build your project with this SDK. Try changing the SDK version of your app in the tiapp.xml and build it again. Good luck!

```
  <sdk-version>3.2.0.GA</sdk-version>
```